# Kindly provide the source code to determine the last item in the ListView

Tags: android

I am trying to implementing pagination in Android.
Currently I am displaying in ListView  , a list of 10 items where the data for the list items exist in the database.

Each list item contains an thumbnail Image Url , a text data

I have the following requirement.
i> When the user scrolls  to the 10 th list item , I am calling a webservice method of the server to fetch the next set of records.

My question is how can I determine when the user scrolls to the 10 th list item , what kind of validation can I make.

Kindly provide me the sample source code.

Warm Regards,

CB

Comment: I am trying to check the count of the item but I think I need to check the scroll , whether it is at the end of the list. How can I do the validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to fetch the next set of records when 10th item is visible on the list then write a condition in `OnScrollListener` similar to this...

```
mListView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)
        {
            if(view.getLastVisiblePosition() == 10)
            {
                // do operation to retrieve other data into listview
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks friend for the reply . I have also raised another question in forum which is related to the above question "Code to create a small progressdialog in Android at the end of screen to populate more data & display in the same screen"   . Kindly help if you have any ideas on the same